# Win10+ROS 2: rosdep install errors: unsupported OS

Tags: ros, windows10

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am getting some error on running rosdep install:

> ```
> rosdep install --from-paths ./src --ignore-src -r -y --rosdistro galactic
> ```

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies:
cyclonedds: Unsupported OS [windows] 
rmw_fastrtps_shared_cpp: Unsupported OS [windows] 
rmw_cyclonedds_cpp: Unsupported OS [windows] 
rmw_fastrtps_dynamic_cpp: Unsupported OS [windows]
rmw_fastrtps_cpp: Unsupported OS [windows]
Continuing to install resolvable dependencies...
#All required rosdeps installed successfully
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382123/win10+ros-2:-rosdep-install-errors:-unsupported-os/) by [Lila](https://answers.ros.org/users/77447/lila/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2021-07-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-07-09**:
I would really recommend to *not* use `-r` in these command lines. It's just going to give the impression `rosdep` actually did something useful, while in reality it just ran into errors and gave up.

Then it merrily prints:

```
Continuing to install resolvable dependencies...
#All required rosdeps installed successfully
```

and if you don't pay attention, it's almost as-if things are ok ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no package manager on Windows. Unfortunately that means that `rosdep` cannot work there either as it relies on using a package manager to install the dependencies. The Windows installation instructions don't use `rosdep` they will be used by Linux and other platforms.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2022-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1